# Undo Git reset in Talend

Tags: git, talend

I was in project A with uncommitted work, switched to project B quickly to check some code (didn't change anything). When I've tried to switch back to project A, Talend popped up several 'commit, reset or cancel' boxes, i don't know why. I panicked and clicked reset as i hadn't changed anything in project B. However, now back in project A I've lost all my recent work. I can obviously do a pull and get back to where i was at the last commit, but as i said i had uncommitted dev changes in my workspace. Is there anyway to get my workspace back to where it was before this reset command?

I understand with Git you would use reflog but in Talend both the Git Reflog and Git Rebase Interactive views are blank for some reason so i can't use them.

Thanks

Comment: i feel like you are depending on whatever IDE you are using's local cache because if you hadn't at least added those files into the index, git didn't store them

Comment: @eftshift0 i was afraid of that. It's Talend and it's absolute hot dog leavings